# I posted on the question on the wrong site, can I move it?

Tags: support

I posted a question on stackoverflow.com somebody commented that it would be more appropriate on magento.stackexchange.com. Is there a way to move it or should I repost?

Comment: Good work - looking forward to seeing the answers to it when it gets migrated, I think it's a really interesting question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flag the post for moderator attention using the "other" reason to ask for the question to be moved.  If they feel that the post belongs on the target site, and that the question qualified for migration, they will move it.

If they feel that the question, as it stands, wouldn't be a great question on that site then they may not.  In that case you should read up on the site someone brought up; look through it's scope to find out what it is really about and how it differs from other sites.  Look at the specific guidelines that that site gives for new questions.  Don't just copy/paste your question to that site; re-write the question so that it is specifically tailored to that site and its audience.

Comment: Thankyou. I flagged it for moderator attention as you suggested.